# Read a text file and return a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have some doubts with a python example.

I want to have a function that receives a text file name as input and returns a dictionary in which each word, separated by space, is associated with a list with the number of the lines in which that word appears.

For example for this example:

```
Example of python program.
Basic python program.
```

The result should be:

```
d['Example] = [1]
d['of'] = [1]
d['python']= [1,2]
d['program'] = [1,2]
d['Basic'] = [2]
```

Im doing like below to read the text file, I have a test.txt file and I enter that test.txt file I don't see any results.

```
 with open(input("Enter Filename: "),'r') as inF:
    newDict = {}
    inF = open(input("Enter Filename: "),'r')
    for line in inF:
        splitLine = line.split()
        newDict[(splitLine[0])] = ",".join(splitLine[1:])
```

Comment: this line seems redundant : `inF = open(input("Enter Filename: "),'r')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)

with open('test.txt') as f:
    for cnt, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        for word in line.strip().split():
            data[word].append(cnt)

print(data)
```

Output:

```
'Example': [1], 
'of': [1], 
'python': [1, 2], 
'program.': [1, 2], 
'Basic': [2]
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain this "for cnt, line in enumerate(f, 1):"?

Comment: @jon enumerate function returns tuple with counter and value returned by ittarable. So in this case enumerator function returns each time line from the file + counter. By default counter starts with 0, and in your case you would like to have line started from 1 instead of 0. So when enumerator returns tuple you unpack it to two variables cnt(counter) and line. You can find more information about enumerate at: http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html